# Why doesn't the image change size when I minimize the screen?

Tags: html, css, image

Why doesn't the image change size when I make the screen smaller? I want to make my image re-size when I make the screen bigger or smaller. this is what I was trying using VS code. I am new to programming so I am kinda stuck. any help would be appreciated.!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pricing</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width initial-scale:1.0">

    <style>
        img{height:auto;
        width:fit-content}
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style=font-family:impact;font-size:100px;color:darkblue;text-align:center> Class Fee 2021</h1>
    
    
    <table style="border: 1px solid black; width:75%;text-align:center">
    <tr style="background-color:royalblue;color:white">
        <th>Membership Type</th>
        <th>Class Limit (Per week)</th>
        <th>Weekly Fee</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">basic Memebrship</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">3</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">50</td>
 </tr>
    </table>


<img src=boxingback.jpg  alt='wallpaper'>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes which may or may not be an issue. Also, what's f1? Do you mean h1? By "minimize" do you mean making the screen smaller? Please clean up your code and clarify the issue.

Comment: this is my second day messing around with html. Sorry about the lack of clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `width` to "100%"  (instead of `width:fit-content`, which doesn't exist) and use quotes for the `src` attribute value in your `img` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pricing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width initial-scale:1.0">

  <style>
    img {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 style=font-family:impact;font-size:100px;color:darkblue;text-align:center> Class Fee 2021</h1>


  <table style="border: 1px solid black; width:75%;text-align:center">
    <tr style="background-color:royalblue;color:white">
      <th>Membership Type</th>
      <th>Class Limit (Per week)</th>
      <th>Weekly Fee</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px;">basic Memebrship</td>
      <td style="padding-left:10px;">3</td>
      <td style="padding-left:10px;">50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/900" alt='wallpaper'>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Johannes. Changing width to "100%" fixed it for me. I was wondering if it works the same with background images?